# Expressjs express-validator sanitize xss image

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have made a upload function and use connect-form with formidable and https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator. I am trying to sanitize an image from xss. But i get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`. So where do i get the actual image to sanitize?

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next){

    req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {

            //------>Sanitize image from xss??
            req.sanitize(?).xss(true);

            res.send('/images/users/' + files.file.filename);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you actually using `req.sanitize(?)` with a question mark there or was that a copy typo?

Comment: No thats no typo. i've been trying to get the image there. The question mark is there to point out that i dont know what to put here.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
var image = req.sanitize('image_field_name').xss(true);
```

rather than:

```
var image = req.sanitize(value_of_image_from_form).xss(true);
```

Comment: Its still the same, get the same error message `Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined`. Can't seem to find a way to target the image...

Comment: Ok - I checked it again and it seems to throw this error when req.body[image_field_name] is undefined, so you should check form value, e.g.
`var val = req.body[image_field_name] || '';`